# 12 week average query returns distorted values due to incomplete weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my main query I have a sub query to return the average net sales over a 12 week period, however due to restaurants being closed due to renovations or expansion it is distorting the value.

How would I change my query to not count the days where net is null?

```
SELECT                 System_RestaurantDateJoined.StoreKey, System_RestaurantDateJoined.RestaurantName, System_RestaurantDateJoined.Ownership 
                      ,System_RestaurantDateJoined.LeaseEagle_ID, System_RestaurantDateJoined.State, System_RestaurantDateJoined.DateKey,   
CASE WHEN DimLFL.Commentary = 'New Rest' THEN 'Category 1 - New Rest as flagged in LFL File'
WHEN DimLFL.Commentary = 'Mjr Reno' THEN 'Category 2 - Reno Rest as flagged in LFL File'
WHEN DimLFL.Commentary = 'Min Reno' THEN 'Category 2 - Reno Rest as flagged in LFL File'
WHEN DimLFL.Commentary = 'Temp Close' THEN 'Category 3 - Temp Closure'
WHEN ISNULL(Daily_Sales_Summary.Net, 1) <= 1 THEN 'Category 4 - Missing Data' 
WHEN ISNULL(Daily_Sales_Summary.LastYear_Net, 1) = 1 THEN 'Category 6 - No sales last year'
WHEN ISNULL(Daily_Sales_Summary.[LastWeek_Net],1) <= 1 THEN 'Category 7 - Missing Data for Last Week'
ELSE    'Category 5 - Potential Over/Under stated sales'
END as Category
                      ,Daily_Sales_Summary.Net, Daily_Sales_Summary.[LastWeek_Net], Daily_Sales_Summary.LastYear_Net
                      ,ISNULL(Daily_Sales_Summary.[12Week_Net], (SELECT     AVG(Net) AS AVGNET
FROM         (SELECT     TOP (12) Net
                       FROM           FactBankingAndDailySummary AS FB INNER JOIN
                      DimDate ON FB.DateKey = DimDate.DateKey
                       WHERE      (FB.StoreKey = System_RestaurantDateJoined.StoreKey) AND (FB.DateKey <= System_RestaurantDateJoined.DateKey) AND 
                                              (DimDate.DayNameOfWeek = System_RestaurantDateJoined.DayNameOfWeek) AND (FB.DateKey >= (FB.DateKey - 84))
                       ORDER BY FB.DateKey, StoreKey DESC) AS WKAV)) AS [12Week_Net]
                      ,Daily_Sales_Summary.TransactionCount,Daily_Sales_Summary.[LastWeek_TransactionCount]
                      ,Daily_Sales_Summary.LastYear_TransactionCount, Daily_Sales_Summary.[12Week_TransactionCount], System_RestaurantDateJoined.FullDate
                      ,System_RestaurantDateJoined.DayNameOfWeek, System_RestaurantDateJoined.FinancialWC, System_RestaurantDateJoined.strFinancialWeek
                      ,DimLFL.Commentary
FROM         Daily_Sales_Summary RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      System_RestaurantDateJoined LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                      DimLFL ON System_RestaurantDateJoined.StoreKey = DimLFL.StoreKey AND System_RestaurantDateJoined.DateKey = DimLFL.DateKey ON 
                      Daily_Sales_Summary.RedCatID = System_RestaurantDateJoined.StoreKey AND 
                      Daily_Sales_Summary.DateKey = System_RestaurantDateJoined.DateKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement your average as `Sum(Value) * 1.0 / Count([something])` where `[something]` is an expression that returns null when the data should not be counted in the denominator. If `Value` is null when there is no data, then it is simply `Sum(Value) * 1.0 / Count(Value)`.